# python replace records in variable

Tags: python, string, variables

I have:

x = "abcdefghi", and I want to replace record from that variable with another record.

for example:

x = "abcdefghi"
x.replace(x[1], x[1+2]), and I want to do a such thing to all records in that variable

x= 'abcdefghi'

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if i < 4:
        x =(alp.replace(alp[i], alp[i+2]))
        print x
```

result is:  "efefefghi"
but it supposed to be: "bdefefefghi"

Comment: `for i in range(len(x)): if i < 4:`... hm...

Comment: Where the `alp` come from?

Comment: Please explain _how_ do you expect to get `bdefefefghi` seems like a different length string

Comment: alp is the same as x, I forgot to change it whle ctrl + v from my project, and about "different length string", it is just the same mistake, forgot to edit it after ctrl + v.

Comment: @DavidDav what happens to the end chars? `h` and `i` their `index+2` would be `IndexError` Whats the expectation there ?

Comment: Please edit it so we can see the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how `replace` works. It does not replace "char at #" with "char at #". It actually replaces all occurrences of a given character.

When you get to `x.replace(x[2], x[4])` you already have same character at `x[0]` and `x[2]`. Therefore, both of them get replaced with `x[4]`.

See:

```
>>> x = "abcde"
>>> x = x.replace(x[0], x[2])    # == replace("a", "c")
>>> x
'cbcde'
>>> x = x.replace(x[2], x[4])    # == replace("c", "e")
>>> x
'ebede'
```

To get your code working, I suggest this:

```
x = "abcdefghi"
x = list(x)
for i in range(len(x)):
    if i < 4:
        x[i] = x[i+2]
        print "".join(x)
```

Result:

```
cbcdefghi
cdcdefghi
cdedefghi
cdefefghi
```

Or even without iteration:

```
x = "abcdefghi"
x = list(x)
x[0:4] = x[2:6]
print "".join(x)
```

Result:

```
cdefefghi
```